# In C# .NET, is there a way to scrape dynamic data from an ajax web page?

Tags: c#, html, ajax, web-scraping

I'd love to poll a web page that has constantly updating dynamic data, and grab that data. I don't want to reload the entire page every second. Is there way to grab that data without reloading the page?

I'm coding as a console app for demo purposes.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried emulating the behaviour of a real browser, ie.. making the AJAX calls, and parsing the results?

Comment: Define "dynamic data."  Does the page return static content that's frequently updated on their server, or does the page have a lot of JavaScript/AJAX that updates its data on the fly?

Comment: Thanks guys- It's sort of like a stock ticker. I'm not triggering the updates- they just happen periodically. I've been using PhantomJS (a headless WebKit browser) but would prefer a C# solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.  For starters, HTTP is stateless.  When you perform an HTTP request, you'll always get static data back, even if dynamic routines were used to generate it.

Doesn't sound like you can hit the data used to construct the page in any other way ( i.e. direct link into DB, Web service, etc ) - if you could you wouldn't be scraping web pages.

Even if you could do that, wouldn't make much of a difference.  You're still going to have to compare what you have now with the data the remote service has.  Absent some sort of push notification, you're polling, and if you're polling, yes, you have to check all the time.

Comment: Thanks Paul- I was telling the guys above I've been using PhantomJS (a headless web-kit browser) to do this with mixed results. I'm not a skilled Javascript developer and would prefer to do it in C#. I'm thinking a browser plug-in might be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the header data returned to check the last modified date:

```
HttpWebResponse.LastModified
```

...however, it's completely up to the server to set this date -- so it may or may not be accurate.

Another option to prevent manual scraping may be to simply get a checksum on the data returned.  You could store it off and compare the markup's sum to what you have stored.

Comment: Thanks George- I'm not sure, but it seems like I'll still have to reload the page every second? I'm thinking writing a browser plug-in might be a better way to go, unless William's HTML Application(HTA) idea works.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider writing the application an an HTML Application (HTA).
This gives you full browser capability, plus the ability to hook into events, and display the data in another window, or write to a disk file.

Comment: Thanks William! Do you have a link for that- I've never heard of it. Sounds promising. Cheers!